# How to read multiple integers without symbols out of arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, bufferedreader, readfile

I need to read multiple integers which are written in the format `(4, 5), 242`. There are 10 lines and each line differs from the other. For example the second line could be something like `(11, 24, 5, 6, 2, 7), 43`.

I want to use these values in a method with the parameter ( int[] n, int x).I want to *print the size of input of n for each line*.

How can I do that?

Comment: Slow down. Which aspect of this problem are you unable to solve?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I cant print the size of input of n for each line.

Comment: @NikosTzianas explain please

Comment: This can be done easily using regex, have you tried something already?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I have never worked with regex, sorry, could you explain me what it is ?

Comment: ok, so you have an input file that consists of lines, each line contains a parentheses delimited sequence of integers separated by commas, and then a final integer separated from the closed parenthesis by a comma. Think of how you would break such a line into the individual pieces I've just mentioned. Look at some of the methods of the `String` class, like `indexOf()`, `substring()`, and `split()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straight forward solution that you can apply while reading in your data from your filed:

- treat each line as string
- remove all characters but digits and commas

Now you should be left with strings like "2,3,4,5".

You can use the split() method on the String class to turn such a string into an array that contains the different numbers only (by splitting on ","). Finally, you parse the number strings. Meaning: you iterate the array of number *strings* and you use Integer.psrseInt() to turn each of that strings into an int or Integer value. Which you then can add to a new list (of Integer) for example!

As this is probably some sort of homework, the above is meant as inspiration, turning it into code is left as exercise to the reader.

Comment: I insist in not editting the .txt file where I read from. It has to be in that format

Comment: Basically, remove anything but digits and , `[^\d,]`

Comment: Exactly! The method you are looking for is called "replaceAll()"

Comment: I am sorry, i missunderstood your answer. But the split() method, it only works for Strings, right? I am using arraylist<Integer>, is there a similar method like split() for that type?